Fock State Generation in Trapped Ions
I am trying to understand the fock generation protocol explained here: https://amowiki.odl.mit.edu/index.php/Quantum_control_and_trapped_ions
What I am confused about is what experimental considerations are needed to transition $|g,0\rangle \rightarrow |e,1\rangle$. From how they explain it, it seems like they tune the parameters and waiting a select time until the two state system flips.
However, in a previous discussion on the blue detuning hamiltonian (https://amowiki.odl.mit.edu/index.php/Laser_cooling_of_trapped_ions), the result they got was:
$$H_I = \frac{i \eta \hbar \Omega}{2} \left(\sigma_+ a^{\dagger} - \sigma_-a \right)$$
When evolving this state via unitary time evolution we would get:
$$e^{-iH_I t/\hbar}|g,0\rangle = e^{\frac{ \eta  \Omega}{2} \left(\sigma_+ a^{\dagger} - \sigma_-a \right)t}|g,0\rangle$$
$$ 1 + \frac{ \eta  \Omega}{2} \left(\sigma_+ a^{\dagger} - \sigma_-a \right)t + \frac{2}{2}(\frac{ \eta  \Omega}{2} \left(\sigma_+ a^{\dagger} - \sigma_-a \right)t)^2 + ... |g,0\rangle$$
$$ = |g,0\rangle + \frac{\eta \Omega t}{2}|e,1\rangle$$
Experimentally, I would interpret this as shinning the laser for a sufficiently long enough t such that the probability is basically $|e,1\rangle$. However, this seems contrary to the precession-like explanation with some rabi frequency I see elsewhere for this mechanism. Could someone help me resolve this?
